# send is not supported, because no request channel has been configured

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to configure integration flow with gateway. Using Java DSL on kotlin.

Gateway config:

```
@MessagingGateway(name = "tdiOutSenderGateway")
interface TdiOutSenderGateway {
    fun send(packet: PhasorEnricher.Packet)
}
```

Flow config:

```
@Bean
open fun tdiOutSendFlow() = IntegrationFlows
    .from(TdiOutSenderGateway::class.java)
    .transform(tdiOutSenderRouter())
    .get()!!
```

got `send is not supported, because no request channel has been configured` 
docs: request channel will be autoconfigured.

- `@IntegrationComponentScan` exists
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#java-dsl-gateway readed and used as base
- double checked: I am using exactly this gateway

Is there any additional setting I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Of course, transform should return something, there should be `route` or `handle`.
2. But even I fixed #1 I faced with that: Void kotlin functions return `Unit`. Spring integrations checks `Unit == null` which is `false`, tries to find the next channel and throw an error. The fix is to use kotlin lambda and return `null` explicitly.
3. After working with Spring Integration and kotlin these 8 months I decided to try to create Kotlin DSL for Spring Integration (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3016)

Kotlin Unit: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions

---

P.S.: Of course I solved it earlier, not after 8 months.